# Modifying multiple views with same id

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view whose purpose is to draw a horizontal line (section delimiter).

```
<View
    android:id="@id/ViewHorizontalLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="@color/ColorGrey" />
```

I have a number of those in my fragment, and wish to modify all of them programmatically in one go. I don't want to create an individual id for each since I'll be doing the same operations on each of them:

```
int margin = 4; // these are random pixel numbers
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mViewHorizontalLine.getLayoutParams();
params.topMargin = margin;
params.bottomMargin = margin;
params.height = 8;
```

I tried creating a ids.xml as suggested by Android Studio for my @id/ViewHorizontalLine but my code is only affecting the first View. Is there a way to affect multiple views with the same ID?

If not, what is the best way to modify multiple views in the same way, programmatically?

Comment: Multiple views with the same ID on the same layout, seriously?

Comment: The idea is reproducing the 'class' attribute from web programming. I thought about IDs but it can be anything.

Comment: So, you must define a style on styles.xml file and then apply in layout for each view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want web styling .class functionality in Android, you must define and style. For instance:

**res/styles.xml**

```
<style name="ViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
</style>
```

Then, in your layout style as many views you want with the same style, but with diferent IDs:

**your_activity_layout.xml**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/ViewHorizontalLine1"
    style="@style/ViewStyle"/>
<View
    android:id="@+id/ViewHorizontalLine2"
    style="@style/ViewStyle"/>
<View
    android:id="@+id/ViewHorizontalLine3"
    style="@style/ViewStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to affect multiple views with the same ID

Using the same ID for multiple views in one layout defeats the whole purpose, yet if needed you need too recursively iterate over your layout and do all the checks you want (namely based on `view.getId()`.